# arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 0

Tags: r, googlevis

I am tring to plot a dataframe (count against time) using googleVis `annotatedTimeline` method.

```
> str(eg)

'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:

 $ dateHour: POSIXct, format: "2016-08-22 00:00:00" "2016-08-22 01:00:00" "2016-08-22 10:00:00" "2016-08-22 11:00:00" ...

 $ count   : int  2036834 2031814 1828108 1824985 1854810 1932097 1981288 1670501 1805873 1779165
```

---

**Eg:**

```
dateHour   count

1  2016-08-22 00:00:00 2036834

2  2016-08-22 01:00:00 2031814

3  2016-08-22 10:00:00 1828108

4  2016-08-22 11:00:00 1824985

5  2016-08-22 12:00:00 1854810

6  2016-08-22 13:00:00 1932097

7  2016-08-22 14:00:00 1981288

8  2016-08-22 15:00:00 1670501

9  2016-08-22 16:00:00 1805873

10 2016-08-22 17:00:00 1779165
```

---

**ERROR on executing this**

```
> A1 <- gvisAnnotatedTimeLine(eg, datevar = "dateHour", numvar =
> "count", 
>                              titlevar = "title", 
>                              options = list(displayAnnotations=TRUE,
>                                             width=600, height=350)) Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
> check.names = TRUE,  : 
> 
>   arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 0
> 
> In addition: Warning message:
> 
> In gvisAnnotatedTimeLine(eg, datevar = "dateHour", numvar = "count", 
> :   AnnotatedTimeline (gvisAnnotatedTimeLine) is Flash based, conisder
> using  AnnotationChart (gvisAnnotationChart) instead. For more details
> visit: goo.gl/tkiEV8
```

I am relative new to R. Any kind of help is welcome . Thanks